# Does xtrabackup(innobackupex) works correctly with innodb_file_per_table (Barracuda)?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-backups

## Trying backup with Percona Xtrabackup

I tried to use Percona Xtrabackup to backup all InnoDB databases in my MySQL data directory.

After executing the following command:

```
innobackupex --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user root --password PASSWD --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf --slave-info  /backup/xtrabackup
```

The process seemed to be completed with the following log:

```
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy
and Percona LLC and/or its affiliates 2009-2013.  All Rights Reserved.
...
innobackupex: Using mysql server version 5.6.12

innobackupex: Created backup directory /nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21
...
[01] Copying /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 to /nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/ibdata1
>> log scanned up to (178807644573)
....
140224 00:05:34  innobackupex: completed OK!
```

## Result

However, the result is too small compared to original database files:

```
# Source database
# du -sm /var/lib/mysql/
19G     /var/lib/mysql/

# Xtrabackup result
# du -sm /nobackup/xtrabackup
455M    /nobackup/xtrabackup
```

## Can Xtrabackup handle databases with innodb_file_per_table?

My InnoDB configuration (in `/path/to/my.cnf`) are as following:

```
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
```

Looking at the execution log, it shows the program only copied `ibdata1` but not other many *.idb files.

I wonder if Xtrabackup cannot handle databases stored with `innodb_file_per_table`. I couldn’t find any hints in its documentation.

Is that true, or any solutions/ideas?

## edit 1: The result seems not to be compressed

```
# find /nobackup/xtrabackup
/nobackup/xtrabackup
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/xtrabackup_logfile
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/ibdata1
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/xtrabackup_checkpoints
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/backup-my.cnf
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/2014-02-24_00-04-21
/nobackup/xtrabackup/2014-02-24_00-04-21/xtrabackup_binary
```

Comment: Yes, xtrabakup works with barracuda. Compression may explain the smaller size. Do files have qp extension?

Comment: @akuzminsky Thanks. I appened the output of `find` of the destination directory above. It seems not to be compressed. (no .qp extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

**`my.cnf` file did not contain `datadir=` configuration** directive. I had passed `--datadir` option to the `mysqld` program instead of putting it on `my.cnf`.

This issue has been solved by just adding `datadir=` configuration to `my.cnf`.